# Defining standard topology on a subset

Tags: general-topology

Can we define a standard topology on the subset of $ℝ^d$? That is, if I take a subset of $ℝ^d$ as $M$ and define an inherited topology on $M$ can I call it the standard topology and use the same rules of standard topology to deal with it?

Comment: You can call it potato if you want

Comment: In most cases the "standard" topology of $\Bbb R^n$ is defined by the norm $\|{\cdot}\|_\infty$ or $\|{\cdot}\|_2$.

Comment: using the same metric/norm topology on the subset produces the same topology as the subspace topology, if that's what you're asking

Comment: Subset can inherit topologies, just fine.  Watch out that you view the topology only in terms of the subset M and not what you think it "should be".  Example. If you view the set (-2,0] $\cup$ {1} $\cup $[3,4], then the set (-1,0) $cup ${1} $\cup $[3,4] $ is an open set.

Comment: We call it **Subspace Topology**. Every subset of a topological space is a topological space with the subspace topology. And this is standard